# Informatica Power center-- How to pass multiple values from transformation to HTTP transformation Base URL

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Trying to pass multiple values in the HTTP transformation URL(Put method) but unable to do it. URL doesn't support query strings

Example:

URL: http://example.com/**page**

need to pass multiple values into the **page**(please see the URL) from another transformation. URL does not support the query string values. Any Idea how to pass multiple values to the URL.

**Page** values like "1234", "5678", "891". So the URL will be as shown below.

```
http://example.com/1234,
http://example.com/5678,
http://example.com/891
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If page numbers are finite,
then you can create that many http transformations in a mapping.
If page numbers are infinite or many, you need to-

1. create a list of pages, create a mapping with http transformations where http://example.com/$pageno
2. create a shell script which will iterate through above list, create a param file with $pageno=1234 etc. and kick off above mapping with this param file.
3. schedule this shell script using another workflow.

HTH